# error in my deployed flask app, shows 500 internal server error

Tags: python, flask

I made a python flask app that can diagnose disease
the app runs fine locally but on deploying it through Heroku I am getting 500 internal I know what that error means but I can't find the error in my app so, I believe eyes on StackOverflow can find it

from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from flask import Flask
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/hello')
def home():
    return 'hello'


@app.route('/rf/<sym1>/<sym2>/<sym3>/<sym4>/<sym5>')
def predict(sym1, sym2, sym3, sym4, sym5):




    l1=['back pain','constipation','abdominal pain','diarrhoea','mild fever','yellow urine',
    'yellowing of eyes','acute liver failure','fluid overload','swelling of stomach',
    'swelled lymph nodes','malaise','blurred and distorted vision','phlegm','throat irritation',
    'redness of eyes','sinus pressure','runny nose','congestion','chest pain','weakness in limbs',
    'fast heart rate','pain during bowel movements','pain in anal region','bloody stool',
    'irritation in anus','neck pain','dizziness','cramps','bruising','obesity','swollen legs',
    'swollen blood vessels','puffy face and eyes','enlarged thyroid','brittle nails',
    'swollen extremeties','excessive hunger','extra marital contacts','drying and tingling lips',
    'slurred speech','knee pain','hip joint pain','muscle weakness','stiff neck','swelling joints',
    'movement stiffness','spinning movements','loss of balance','unsteadiness',
    'weakness of one body side','loss of smell','bladder discomfort','foul smell of urine',
    'continuous feel of urine','passage of gases','internal itching','toxic look (typhos)',
    'depression','irritability','muscle pain','altered sensorium','red spots over body','belly pain',
    'abnormal menstruation','dischromic  patches','watering from eyes','increased 
appetite','polyuria','family history','mucoid sputum',
    'rusty sputum','lack of concentration','visual disturbances','receiving blood transfusion',
    'receiving unsterile injections','coma','stomach bleeding','distention of abdomen',
    'history of alcohol consumption','fluid overload','blood in sputum','prominent veins on calf',
    'palpitations','painful walking','pus filled pimples','blackheads','scurring','skin peeling',
    'silver like dusting','small dents in nails','inflammatory nails','blister','red sore around nose',
    'yellow crust ooze']

     disease=['Fungal infection','Allergy','GERD','Chronic cholestasis','Drug Reaction',
    'Peptic ulcer diseae','AIDS','Diabetes','Gastroenteritis','Bronchial Asthma','Hypertension',
    'Migraine','Cervical spondylosis',
    'Paralysis (brain hemorrhage)','Jaundice','Malaria','Chicken pox','Dengue','Typhoid','hepatitis A',
    'Hepatitis B','Hepatitis C','Hepatitis D','Hepatitis E','Alcoholic hepatitis','Tuberculosis',
    'Common Cold','Pneumonia','Dimorphic hemmorhoids(piles)',
    'Heartattack','Varicoseveins','Hypothyroidism','Hyperthyroidism','Hypoglycemia','Osteoarthristis',
    'Arthritis','(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo','Acne','Urinary tract infection','Psoriasis',
    'Impetigo']

    l2=[]
    for x in range(0,len(l1)):
        l2.append(0)


    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    clf3 = RandomForestClassifier()
    clf3 = clf3.fit(X,np.ravel(y))
    #filename = 'model.sav'
    #pickle.dump(clf3, open(filename, 'wb'))
    model = 
    pickle.load(open(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).replace("",""))+"/asset/model.sav", "rb"))
    print("model loaded")

# calculating accuracy-------------------------------------------------------------------
#from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
#y_pred=clf3.predict(X_test)
#print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
#print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred,normalize=False))
# -----------------------------------------------------
    Symptom1 = '%s' % sym1

    Symptom2 = '%s' % sym2

    Symptom3 = '%s' % sym3

    Symptom4 = '%s' % sym4

    Symptom5 = '%s' % sym5


    psymptoms = [Symptom1,Symptom2,Symptom3,Symptom4,Symptom5]

    for k in range(0,len(l1)):
    # print (k,)
        for z in psymptoms:
            if(z==l1[k]):
                l2[k]=1

    inputtest = [l2]
    predict = model.predict(inputtest)
    predicted=predict[0]
    #print(predicted)
    #assigning a string value to "a"
    for a in range(0,len(disease)):
        if(predicted == a):
            break
   
    return disease[a]#returning the disease

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

If you some Indentation error that's not the problem because It might have wrongly indented while I copy-pasted it on the website

also, the URL directing "/hello" works fine which shows that my predict function has the error

It would nice if you answer it

Regards,
Roshan

Comment: Is this a full method or just part of it? Because I don't see that you are a return something from it...

Comment: `return disease[a]` returns the disease from the disease list and yes it is the full method